# How can I setup an official maven docker image with my own global settings.xml?

Tags: maven, docker

I use docker for the first time in connection with GitLab CI. I am happy that GitLab does most of the work for me. 
I am using the official maven docker image `maven:3-jdk-8` (https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/)

Now I would like to set the global `settings.xml` on that docker image, which contains data to my nexus server for the deploy phase.

I tried to follow this guide: [Adding a directory and image in the docker image](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-update-add-a-file-in-the-docker-image/) , but unfortunally I cannot connect to the bash of the docker image.

```
root@build:~# docker run maven:3-jdk-8 /bin/bash -it
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
root@7d62e8b066f7:/# exit
```

How can I add my own global `settings.xml` to my maven docker image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create/ build your own image using a `Dockerfile` extending the existing maven docker image i.e `maven:3-jdk-8` in your case

And in there you can add a line something like below:-

```
COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/
```

You can have multiple `settings.xml` named differently(obviously) and you can use them as per the requirements

like `mvn <goal> -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-<somename>.xml`

goal and someone being different as per the usage

Comment: The building seems to have worked. The new image is listed on the host system. Although I am getting the error message `Pulling docker image maven:3-jdk-8-Nexus ...
ERROR: Job failed: Error response from daemon: manifest for maven:3-jdk-8-Nexus not found` when executing my gitlab ci job that should be executed on that image.

Comment: Okay, I think this is a configuration issue with the gitlab ci runner. I'll report back :)

Comment: you can create your own image at gitlab docker repositories

Comment: and pull the same using the gitlab ci

Comment: I could solve it by adding `pull_policy = "if-not-present"` to the  `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`. Now I've got another problem that I get denied to run an executable which gets downloaded during the job. As soon as I've solved this, I can tell you if it worked with the `settings.xml` :)

Comment: Alright all set. I used a bad maven plugin. Perfect it works! Thanks a lot.